# How to install a Rust target for a specific rustup toolchain?

Tags: rust, cross-compiling

I am using `rustc` and `cargo` on my 64-bit Windows machine to compile a 32-bit application. This works fine when using the stable toolchain, but when I try to use the beta toolchain it fails.

The beta toolchain was successfully installed with `rustup install beta`. In the project folder there is a `.cargo/config.toml` file containing the following lines:

```
[build]
target = "i686-pc-windows-msvc"

[target.i686-pc-windows-msvc]
rustflags = ["-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static"]
```

When running `cargo +beta build` the following error occurs:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `i686-pc-windows-msvc` target may not be installed
```

I have tried running `rustup target add i686-pc-windows-msvc` to fix the issue but it didn't help; `rustup target list` even displays it as "installed". Possibly this command only adds the target for stable, and I couldn't find out how to specify the beta toolchain.

How can I add another (non-default) target for the beta toolchain?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Read the help for `rustup target add`:

```
$ rustup target add --help
rustup-target-add
Add a target to a Rust toolchain

USAGE:
    rustup target add [OPTIONS] <target>...

FLAGS:
    -h, --help    Prints help information

OPTIONS:
        --toolchain <toolchain>    Toolchain name, such as 'stable', 'nightly', or '1.8.0'. For more information see
                                   `rustup help toolchain`
```

Thus you want:

```
rustup target add i686-pc-windows-msvc --toolchain beta
```

I believe it will add the target to the "current" toolchain by default, so you could also do:

```
rustup override set beta               # in your project directory
rustup target add i686-pc-windows-msvc #
cargo build                            # no more +beta
```

---

> `rustup target list` even displays it as "installed"

Read the help for `rustup target list`:

```
$ rustup target list --help
rustup-target-list
List installed and available targets

USAGE:
    rustup target list [OPTIONS]

FLAGS:
    -h, --help    Prints help information

OPTIONS:
        --toolchain <toolchain>    Toolchain name, such as 'stable', 'nightly', or '1.8.0'. For more information see
                                   `rustup help toolchain`
```

Thus you want:

```
rustup target list --toolchain beta
```

Comment: I only looked at `rustup target --help` before, didn't know there is more information to be requested for each sub-command.

Answer (score 0):

Apart of installing a new target described in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53210209/1143349) above, you might also need to setup your new installed target as a default target.

In order to check all available or installed targets you use:

```
rustup target list
```

You can also check your default target by executing:

```
rustup default
```

If you want to change the default target you can use the following command:

```
rustup default <YOUR_TARGET_NAME>
```

for example: `rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`

Also if you need to change a default target to your specific directory, you can create a file with name `rust-toolchain` and include the target name as a content:

```
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

[image]